# Django Rest Framework File Upload Says Document Not Submitted

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I upload a file through requests module it says no document submitted

*models.py*:

```
class Apidocument(models.Model):
    iden = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='media/documents')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

*serializer.py*:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    document = serializers.FileField(max_length=None,use_url =True)
    class Meta():
        model = Apidocument
        fields = ('uploaded_at','document')
```

*views.py*:

```
class ApiViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Apidocument.objects.all().order_by('-uploaded_at')
    serializer_class = DataSerializer


files = {"file": ('b839', open('/home/user/b839.jpeg', 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')}
resp = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/upload/', files=files)
```

Comment: In addition to @Haren Lewis' answer below, make sure to add `MultipartParser` to the view's parser classes if it is already not part of the default parsers

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using a `ModelSerializer` and then defining a `document` field on the serializer, I think it's not required to specify document `field` on the serializer as `ModelSerializer` should include it anyways.

Also since you are using field name as `document`, it requires document key in the request associated with the file (at least that's how it is in xhr). So your requests object should look something like this:

`files = {"document": ('b839', open('/home/user/b839.jpeg', 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')}`.

Hope this works.